# How to change button fontSize in React Native?

Tags: react-native

How can I change the following button's font size? Using the style attribute with fontSize doesn't work.

```
   <Button
       style={{fontSize: 32}}
       uppercase={false}
       mode="contained">
     Some text
   </Button>
```

Comment: which type of button do you use? `react-native` or `native-base` or `react-native-element` or any other. please describe. I hope we will help you in better way

Comment: @shammi, I use the basic react native button https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button

Comment: ok sir. please try this answer which is I posted now

Answer (score 6):

The React Native Button is very limited in what you can do, see; https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button

It does not have a style prop, and you don't set fontSize.

If you want to have more control over the appearance you should use one of the TouchableXXXX' components like TouchableOpacity They are really easy to use :-)
I have make a button for you . hope it will useful for you

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{height:50,backgroundColor:"skyblue",alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}}>
     <Text style={{fontSize:32,}}>Some Text</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 3):

I use the Text component inside TouchableXXX for every button, it's more flexible and works fine, you can also try to make you own button component and passing props that you want to control (fontsize, colors ...):

```
 <TouchableHighlight onPress={handelPress} style={styles.buttonStyle}>
     <Text style={styles.buttonTextStyle}>Click here</Text>
 </TouchableHighlight>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 'react-native-elements' button, use titleStyle to set font size.

```
import {Input, Button} from 'react-native-elements';

<Button
   titleStyle={{
       color: "white",
       fontSize: 16,
   }}
   buttonStyle={{
       backgroundColor: "white",
       borderRadius: 60,
       flex: 1,  
   }}

   title="Click here"
/>
```

For React-native Button, you can use use TouchableOpacity.

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{height:50}}>
     <Text style={{fontSize:36}}>Click here</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```